# CSS applying Max-height and Auto height property at the same time for an image

Tags: html, css

How do I set the the `max-height:270px` and `height:auto` simultaneously such that if a content(image) is too large it should shorten its dimensions and put it under `270px`, else it should be an `auto` height.

I tried with `overflow-Y` but I dont want a scrollbar, just a mini version of the pic. How can I do that?

Comment: Don't understand it right. So you have for example a image with a absolute height of 500px. But the image should have a max-height of 270px. But what do you want with height:auto?

Comment: With auto I want that if an image is of size,say 100px, the div height should automatically be set to 100px, but in worst case , as in 500px it should not overlimit 270px

Comment: Isn't `max-height:270px` alone responding to your needs ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**CHANGED CODE ::** TRY IT

```
img{
height:100%;
max-height:270px;
}
```

Comment: overflow hidden cuts the image. It does not show the full image. I want the large image to shorten its dimensions automatically. Currently with height:270px, the large images shortens properly but the div with small images or with textual content also has the same height of 270px thereby wasting the space. I want something like auto.

Comment: have you tried it????it's not suppose to cut/crop an image..i have used `overflow:hidden;` in wrapper div...and i have put a limit to max-height and width for that image...thats mean the photo will be resized if it crosses the limit...there is no chance for crop...`overflow:hidden;` in wrapping div is used here just cover the whole area take by that image

Comment: I want to resize. If I set `height:270px` the image is automatically resized to 270px, but the other divs are also resized to 270px(which I dont want). With `overflow:hidden` only a portion of the image is seen.

Answer (score 1):

use like this

```
height:auto;
max-height: 270;
Overflow:hidden;
```

max-height will restrict your images height to that px if the image height is higher than that.
giving any specific height will scale the image if the height amount is less than the image height.
Overflow hidden will hide the scroll bar.

Comment: overflow hidden cuts the image. It does not show the full image. I want the large image to shorten its dimensions  automatically. Currently with `height:270px`, the large images shortens properly but the div with small images or with textual content also has the same height of 270px thereby wasting the space. I want something like `auto`.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
height: 0; /*rather than auto*/
max-height: 270px;
```

Comment: Naa. Everything overflows. The image gets out the div tab and overlays on other divs as well. Even the div with textual content also overflows.

Comment: Did you try something 0px or 0%?

Comment: With both px and %, the image overflows the size limit

Comment: I'm feeling anything other try height: 1em; this solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

do not apply a width in the image tag. set your css to `max-width:100%; max-height:100%;`

Also, read this http://unstoppablerobotninja.com/entry/fluid-images

Answer (score 0):

You would just do this:

```
<img style="max-height:270px" src="500x500.png" alt="I am resized to 270x270"> 
<img style="max-height:270px" src="200x200.png" alt="I am not resized">
```

By not setting a height/width it allows the browser to display the image at it's native size up to the limit you set via `max-height`.

While leaving out the h/w is not best practice, it accomplishes easily what you are trying to do and will just take a fraction of a second longer to load the page since the browser has to calculate each image size before displaying it.

Example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mUXut/)

Answer (score -1):

As far as i understand you have 2 code one work for google chrome and another for all other browsers how to combine them.(if not you can edit my code  alittle bit to satisfy your needs)
You could try something like this:

```
<?PHP if($browser == "Chrome"){ ?>
<!--HTML Code for Chrome browser-->
<?PHP }else { ?>
<!--Code for other browsers-->
<?PHP } ?>
```

This would help for cross browsers scripts